# Today I have been meeting and today I have met

Tags: meaning-in-context, present-perfect, present-tense, present-perfect-progressive

Is there any difference between "Today I have been meeting some of the people affected by the flood" and "Today I have met some of the people affected by the flood"?

Does "have been meeting" imply you have spent a lot of time talking to these people? Or is there no real difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference (as usual for aspectual constructions like this) lies entirely in the way the speaker is inviting the hearers to construct the temporal relationships.

If they say *I have met*, this is neutral, and does not suggest any particular temporal focus. If they say *I have been meeting*, they are inviting the hearers to see the meeting as a continuing process. This *might* imply that it took a long time, but does not necessarily do so.

It does not necessarily convey any objective difference at all. But the meaning (in an extended sense) is not the same, because of the way the speaker is setting the temporal focus or structure.

Comment: By "continuing process" do you mean the meeting is still continuing at this moment? Or is "continuing process" also possible if the meeting has finished?

Comment: As I said, the choice does not necessarily convey any objective difference. With _have been meeting_, the meetings could be continuing (but are not necessarily doing so). With _met_, the meetings are probably not continuing (but they might be: the speaker might just be choosing to focus on the ones that have already taken place rather than regarding them as part of a continuing series).

Comment: In my "I have been meeting" example the meetings have stopped. There will be no more meetings. Is the continuous still possible?

Comment: Yes, the continuous is still possible. I will say it a third time: there is no necessary difference in the objective reality conveyed by the two forms. A simple past means that the speaker is thinking of the meetings they have had as finished, which _suggests_ that there are no more meetings, but does not rule out that possibility. A continuous form says that the speaker is focussing on the continuing activity in the past during the day, but does not suggest whether they are continuing or not.